# How to do both Azure Active Directory Single Sign On and Forms Authentications on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

We have the legacy system developed by MVC 4 using Forms Authentication and Basic Authentication for Web API (there is no OWIN so far).

Now we have lots of clients which want to do single sign on into our system, so we use Azure Active Directory (AAD) to store client's users.

Now the situation is we want to revise the login workflow to adapt with AAD. The login page has no changes, under the hood, we check whether user exists on our system (using our database), it allows user to access. If not, we continue to check user on AAD, we don't want to re-direct to Azure login page in this case.

I have done tons of reading but have not much clear how to do this? We also consider to upgrade to MVC 5 in order to use OWIN middleware authentication if it's fine with situation.

Comment: Is there any reason behind the requirement to not to use any of passive authentication protocols implemented by the WAAD?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Sorry for this late response, using WAAD passive authentication (OpenIdConnect or OAuth2) with redirect to Azure login page, we don't want that. Instead we uses ADAL .NET to Authenticate Users via Username/Password and here is the link: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use Custom SSO applications from the Application gallery in AAD. When doing this, AAD will parse the form that the AAD users are using to login to the system. When a user that is already logged in to AAD enters your application, the AAD browser plugin or app will enter the username and password automatically.

More information on this blog: http://www.edutech.me.uk/microsoft/identity-and-access-management/active-directory/azure-ad-custom-saas-applications-for-any-3rd-party-service/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have read the article and am not sure how to apply on my situation. The login page is on our application we don't want to re-direct to Azure login page, we check if user exists in our system (our database), if no, continue to check if user exists on AAD via ADAL. Could you please explain more to how to apply.

Comment: Also, I see the note that this feature is still in public review, and not advised to use in production, does it come to stable for now?

Comment: Are you looking for authentication solutions of Single Sign On (SSO)? because on the comment you wrote in the question you give a link to the ADAL example that shows how to use the username/password flow in ADAL. The solution I gave you is for SSO with AAD.

Comment: I am looking for the "mixed mode" between AAD SSO and FormsAuthentication on our system. Thanks for your answer, I need to investigate more in order to have more detail question

Comment: Hi, Did you get any luck with your question? If yes can you share the idea or the solution of how to achieve this?