# ASP.NET 5 API - Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently developing an application and almost finished my front-end.
So I want to start with the back-end.

I used to program in ASP.NET 4, but since I start a brand new application (B2C and B2B) I thought it might be interesting to make it in ASP.NET 5 API.

Now my biggest issue is authentication.
There is no standard implementation provided in the template.

I'm only interested in Azure AD Authentication and prefer Azure B2C AD for really cutting the edge.

I only find documentation to use Azure AD B2C in ASP.NET 4.
After hours of searching, I still don't find documentation on using Azure AD B2C in an ASP.NET 5 API.

Can someone help me finding proper documentation or help me on the way?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660780/asp-net-identity-using-password-and-azure-active-directory-authentication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a new article from Microsoft is about Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET 5 web app:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnet5/

I guess this is what you are looking for.

By the way, you may also want to check Azure AD B2C limitations and restrictions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-limitations/

Comment: The link is no longer available, but I guess they moved it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/