# How to connect Asp.Net Identity authentication with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I use in my asp.net project UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication protocol to connect to my Azure AD and it works fine.

Today I need authentication too in Asp.net Identity or other authentication type different from Azure AD, but this new authentication must be connected with asp.net (same project pages).

It's two way authentication at the same time, folders different, but in the same project. After authentication redirect to common page.

Can you help me?

Vilela

Comment: Can you explain a bit scenario you want to achieve? Do I understand right that you have two sections in your application where you want to have two different auth providers ?

Comment: Hello Tomasz, thank you for return. Is Right. I need two authentication. The first is authentication by Azure AD successfuly, using email Microsoft. And for other some authentication this people don't have Microsoft Account and need authentication by Login Asp.net Control. 
After both are authenticated the system redirect to Menu.aspx page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the OWIN support multiple identity provider directly. If we config the multiple identity provider, when we click the login button, it will enable users to choose the identity provide to login-in like figure below:

[image]

And here is the code for your reference:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
    //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
    //    clientId: "",
    //    clientSecret: "");

    //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
    //   consumerKey: "",
    //   consumerSecret: "");

    //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
    //   appId: "",
    //   appSecret: "");

    //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    //{
    //    ClientId = "",
    //    ClientSecret = ""
    //});

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "eca61fd9-f491-4f03-a622-90837bbc1711",
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/adfei.onmicrosoft.com",
        });

}
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hey Fei Xue, thank you so much. It's fine now! It helped a lot!